# Java thread lock when trying to lock/unlock with ReetrantLock(true)

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, deadlock

I am having some trouble with a `ReetrantLock(true)` in an application that checks the difference between two images and shows similarity based on a percentage.

For some reason my input thread for reading in the minimum percent for being "similar" calls `lock.lock()` and that particular thread just deadlocks indefinitely but I can't seem to figure out why only that thread is deadlocking.

In the SSCCE below in the main method `main(String[])` the inline `Thread` is used to get input from the console and if I type any number in it correctly stores it but as soon as it calls `lock.lock()` it deadlocks indefinitely and I am unsure why because the `ReetrantLock` has been told to be fair to caller threads and try to order them for when they called.

```
private static volatile boolean running = false;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    webcam2 webcam = new webcam2();
    webcam.start();
    (new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (running)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter Double: ");
                double val = scanner.nextDouble();
                lock.lock(); // locks indefinatly here
                if (val < 0.0D) reset = true;
                dif = val;
                System.out.println("Searching for value: " + dif);
                lock.unlock();
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
    })).start();
}

private static double dif = 0.0D;
private static boolean reset = false;
private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        while (running)
        {
                // show image on window
                lock.lock();
                if (reset == true)
                {
                    reset = false;
                    lock.unlock();
                    doComplexStuffToImage();
                }
                lock.lock();
                doComplexStuffToImage();
                lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void doComplexStuffToImage()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ie)
    {
        //swallow exception
    }
}

public void start()
{
    new Thread(this).start();
    running = true;
}

public void stop()
{
    running = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thread is locking the ReentrantLock and not releasing it.  What "reentrant" means is you can call lock many times, but you must call unlock() the same number of times.  You lock twice, and unlock once so you are not actually unlocking the lock, thus no other process gets a chance.

Comment: oh now I see my stupid mistake, the input thread will only get to run if a reset is called but that can only be called if its not locked. Thanks